# Binding Checkbox Values to database for loading gridTable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<div class="checkboxData">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblStrength" Class="checkBoxFilter" runat="server" DataTextField="language" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cblStrength_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataValueField="language" RepeatLayout="OrderedList" Width="432px">  
    </asp:CheckBoxList> 
</div>
```

The above code is for my Checkboxlist. This Checkboxlist values are dynamically bound from database

```
DataSet dsFilterItems = new DataSet();

CheckBoxList cblStrength = (CheckBoxList)Master.FindControl("cblStrength");
CheckBoxList cblForm = (CheckBoxList)Master.FindControl("cblForm");
CheckBoxList cblSize = (CheckBoxList)Master.FindControl("cblSize");

dsFilterItems = itemsBL.GetItemsForFilter(null, null, strkeywords, null, null, custRole);

if (dsFilterItems.Tables.Count >= 0)
{

    //cblStrength.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    cblStrength.DataSource = dsFilterItems.Tables[0];
    cblStrength.DataTextField = "Strength";
    cblStrength.DataValueField = "Strength";
    cblStrength.DataBind();

    //cblForm.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    cblForm.DataSource = dsFilterItems.Tables[1];
    cblForm.DataTextField = "itemForm";
    cblForm.DataValueField = "itemForm";
    cblForm.DataBind();

    //cblSize.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    cblSize.DataSource = dsFilterItems.Tables[2];
    cblSize.DataTextField = "CF_Size";
    cblSize.DataValueField = "CF_Size";
    cblSize.DataBind();
}
```

The checkbox values are loaded dynamically based on the search...

Now I have to show only checkbox checked values in the datagrid, I have the query for selecting from the database which is shown below

```
SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Strength IN (@cblStrength)
```

But it works only single checkbox value what should I do for Multiple selection and how load datagrid without refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate for sql query to make multiple/comma separate parameter to work. eg.

```
Set @query = 'SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Strength IN ('+@cblStrength+')';
EXEC sp_executesql  @query;
```

Happy Coding!!